# enum ordinal with a string?

Tags: java, enums

I want to make a program that turns letters in to numbers and I wanted to use an Enum to check what number the letter is. To do that I did an Enum with all the letter so now I need to check the ordinal of that letter. I tried

```
String aString ="a";

int letternumber = anEnum.aString.ordinal() //should return 0
```

but aString is not allowed to be a string it needs to be the actual letters. How can I do this?

Comment: how does your enum look like?, how did you plan to build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing you can do to that is

```
MyEnum.valueOf(aString).ordinal()
```

You cannot use a string as a variable like that -- certainly not without reflection, and it's generally inadvisable even with reflection.